# Nagios - host inherit from multiple templates?

Tags: sql-server, nagios

Is it possible to have a host in Nagios use multiple templates?

I'm trying to monitor some MSSQL servers. Some of these are standalone single servers with a single instance, and others are using MSCS to form 2-node HA clusters.

The things I want to monitor on a particular server are different to the things I want to monitor for a particular SQL instance. e.g. I want to use a template `windows-server` to tell me generic things about windows for a given server. Similarly, I'd want to use a specific SQL template called `sql-instance` to monitor SQL-specific things, like connected users, batch requests etc.

For my 2 node clusters, this is quite easy - I have three host definitions: a `windows-server` for each specific node and a `sql-instance` pointing at the cluster dns name.

For single instances, I'd like to be able to have a single host, which uses both the `windows-server` and `sql-instance` templates together, because they both should point at the same hostname. However, any attempts to do:

```
define host {
    use windows-server, sql-instance
}
```

or

```
define host {
    use windows-server
    use sql-instance
}
```

results in nagios only picking up one of the templates and ignoring the other.

So how best can I do multiple template inheritance in Nagios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using a workaround. Instead of having a particular host inherit from multiple templates, I attached my services to various hostgroups and just placed each host in more than one hostgroup:

```
define host {
    use             generic-host
    hostgroups      sql-servers,sql-instances
 }
```

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as the accepted answer for other people to benefit?

Comment: I can in 11 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

How about having one template inherit from the other?  That's how I do it on my nagios.  You can put `use  windows-server` in the `sql-instance` server template definition, and then anything that uses the sql-instance definition will also inherit the windows-server definition.  In this case you may also want to rename sql-instance to win-sql-instance.

Comment: Yes. See example I posted.

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.x, Nagios supports the syntax from your first example out of the box:

```
define host {
  use windows-server,sql-instance
}
```

See the section "Precedence With Multiple Inheritance Sources" in http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectinheritance.html, and "Object Inheritance" in the [changelog](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/whatsnew.html).

(I would have added this as a comment to the accepted answer, but do not have the required reputation to do so)

Answer (score 0):

So far I remember, you'll need to redeclare define host{} every time you have a new host.

Something like that:

```
define host{
   use             windows-server
   host_name       lan
   alias           lan
   address         WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ
}

define host{
   use             sql-instance
   host_name       lan
   alias           lan
   address         WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ
}
```

Hope this will help you.

ps : I can you onto my nagios config file if you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me a "Duplicate definition found for host 'hostname'" error.

Comment: In looking in my nagios, I remembered that I create .cfg for every servers I monitore. DHCP.cfg with define host{use windows-server} in, and so on.

Try creating different .cfg and put your define host in them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my Icinga-environment and it works for Icinga:

```
define host {
                host_name                             Testhost
                address                               192.168.220.1
                check_command                         check-host-alive
                notification_interval                 15
                notification_options                  d,u,r
                max_check_attempts                    3
                active_checks_enabled                 1
                passive_checks_enabled                0
                notifications_enabled                 1
                check_period                          24x7
                notification_period                   24x7
                contact_groups                        admins
                parents                               Email Prim,Source
                use                                   Default_timeperiod_interval_1,Default_timeperiod_interval_10
}
```

I'm not sure about Nagios, but it shouldn't be too different.

Answer (score 0):

in my nagios cfg files all references that have multiple entries for "use template template1,template2" have no spaces in between the first template the comma and the second template.  i added a space before the second template and nagios complained :

```
Error: Template ' template_name' specified in host definition could not be not found (config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/hosts.cfg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Define sql-instance as a host template that in turn uses windows-server as a template.

```
define host{
        name                    windows-server  ; The name of this host template
        use                     generic-host    ; Inherit default values from the generic-host template
        check_period            24x7            ; By default, Windows servers are monitored round the clock
        check_interval          5               ; Actively check the server every 5 minutes
        max_check_attempts      10              ; Check each server 10 times (max)
        check_command           check-host-alive        ; Default command to check if servers are "alive"
        notification_period     24x7            ; Send notification out at any time - day or night
        notification_interval   30              ; Resend notifications every 30 minutes
        notification_options    d,r             ; Only send notifications for specific host states
        contact_groups          admins          ; Notifications get sent to the admins by default
        hostgroups              windows-servers ; Host groups that Windows servers should be a member of
        register                0               ; DONT REGISTER THIS - ITS JUST A TEMPLATE
        }

define host{
        name                    sql-instance    ; The name of this host template
        use                     windows-server  ; Inherit default values from the 
        register                0
        }
```

Then, in your actual host definition, just `use sql-instance` and set `register 1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this means that Nagios will try to monitor host-specific things (CPU load, disk space) about a virtual cluster name, which I don't want it to do.

Comment: I don't think that is true.  Test it and find out.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what growse is saying, it's not at all true.  It will monitor those things under the name of the host.